# assertEquals method not working

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

```
String str = driver.findElement(By.className("phone")).getText();
assertEquals(mobileNumber, str);
```

It display below error message

```
"ComparisonFailure: expected:<720 722 []0043> but was:<720 722 [?]0043>"
```

both values are same, but i dont know why it throw error.

Comment: What happens if you log the two values before assertEquals is executed? What is printed?

Comment: You probably have to log the values in hex form. It looks like there is a non-printable char in front of '0043'

Comment: Can you show the html? That might clear up what the mystery extra character is.

Comment: What vincebowdren said. The `phone` element obviously contains something more than the phone string. A nested element? Extra characters?

Comment: in source code i have found this
    <p>720 722 &shy;0043</p>

Answer (score 0):

Assert equals is not working for strings like you expect.

Try this instead

```
assertTrue(str.equals(mobileNumber));
```